# yq - Search and replace a node's specific value (If exists)

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, yq

I have a helm dependencies chart that I'm willing to programmatically search and replace a specific Chart name with a given version.
For example, here's my file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: my-chart
version: 1.2.3
dependencies:
  - name: dependency-1
    version: 1.0.20
    repository: https://my.registry.com/helm/
  - name: dependency-2
    version: 1.0.1
    repository: https://my.registry.com/helm/
  - name: dependency-3
    version: 1.0.20
    repository: https://my.registry.com/helm/
  - name: dependency-4
    version: 0.3.24
    repository: https://my.registry.com/helm/
  - name: dependency-5
    version: 3.1.2
    repository: https://my.registry.com/helm/
```

I'm trying to work on workflow that would take two inputs:

1. chartName
2. newVersion

Then, when invoked, the workflow will check if `$chartName` exists in `.dependencies` (I was able to achieve that using `select` directive, as following:

```
yq ".dependencies[] | select (.name == \"dependency-3\")" my-chart/Chart.yaml
```

Which only outputs the node that matches the select:

```
$ yq ".dependencies[] | select (.name == \"dependency-3\")" my-chart/Chart.yaml
name: dependency-3
version: 1.0.20
repository: https://my.registry.com/helm/
$
```

And then I tried to use `strenv` directive to update the version to the new one (`$newVersion`), as below:

```
ver=1.0.0 yq ".dependencies[] | select (.name == \"dependency-3\") | strenv(ver)" my-chart/Chart.yaml
```

But it only outputs the updated version, so if I run `yq -i` - it replaces the entire file with simply `1.0.0`:

```
$ ver=1.0.0 yq -i ".dependencies[] | select (.name == \"dependency-3\") | strenv(ver)" my-chart/Chart.yaml
$ cat my-chart/Chart.yaml
1.0.0
```

How can I get `yq` to only update the `version` of the provided dependency name in the `dependencies` array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically already have all the components, just the assignment `=` was missing. All put together:

```bash
chart="dependency-3" newver="2.0.0" yq '
  (.dependencies[] | select (.name == strenv(chart))).version = strenv(newver)
' my-chart/Chart.yaml
```

Use the `-i` option to not just output but update the file.